# issue with backface-visibility:hidden;

Tags: html, css

I'm a begenner and trying tomake the card flip on hover (to show the back side of the card when hover), I've followed a couple videos on YouTube. I kind of got the concept of how to do it, but I can't get the backface-visibility:hidden to work properly.

Here's the my scss code:

```
.card {
perspective: 150rem;
-moz-perspective: 150rem;
height: 400px;
width: 300px;

&:hover &__content {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

&__content {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
transition: all 2.5s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
width: 100%;
}

&__side {
position: absolute;
backface-visibility: hidden; *
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

&__front {
background-color: #333;
background: url(../01_card_flip/img/love.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;

}
&__back {
background-color: pink;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<body>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__content">
        <div class="card__side card__front"></div>
        <div class="card__side card__back">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I have the backface-visibility:hidden;, everything seems normal, but when I hover over it, I can only see the backside of card__front, but card__back is gone. And I have no idea why, please help!

Comment: Please post your HTML as well

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the HTML as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out what the issue is, and here's the answer in case someone is wondering...

backface-visibility:hidden has to be placed on the backside of the card, in my case card__back

Here's the HTML

```
<body>

    <div class="card">
       <div class="card__side card__content">
           <div class="card__front"></div>

           <div class="card__side card__back">
               <h3 class="card__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

And CSS (sass)

```
.card {
    height: 30rem;
    perspective: 150rem;
    -moz-perspective: 150rem;
    width: 20rem;

    &:hover &__content {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    &__content {
        position: relative;
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
        transition: transform 1.5s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &__side {
        position: absolute;
        // backface-visibility: hidden; **THIS WILL NOT WORK ON CHROME**
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    &__front {
        background: url(../01_card_flip/img/love.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &__back {
        backface-visibility: hidden; // PLACE IT RIGHT HERE

        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #7c0a02, #bd574e);
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        width: 100%;
    }

    &__text {
        font-family: 'amita', cursive;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

I'd like the clarify one more thing, for Edge and Firefox, it works perfectly within card__side; HOWEVER, Chrome somehow creates a little pause after the front of the card is flipped, and the back side would suddenly pop up. If anyone knows why that happens, I would love to know about it.

Anyway, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.scene {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.scene:hover .container .content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="scene">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <h3 class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For reference here is the JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/h3dke5to/47/

Use **backface-visibility: visible** to make the flippling of the title visible

Please let me know if it works as you needed

Comment: I have used simple classes for styling and have applied hover functionality with backface hidden on the content class which was not earlier working in the above question basically I have simplified without errors so that desired functionality is achieved

Comment: And if we make backface-visibility: visible; then it will be flipped as desired